# Format Created Date and Modified Date Columns to Display Normal Time

Tags: powershell, date-time

I have a PowerShell script that outputs to CSV all items and files from all Lists and Libraries below:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts/HTG"
foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {


foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach($version in $item.Versions){
$data = @{
"Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
}



Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\NewOutput.csv
```

Below is a sample output of the script:

[image]

The problem is for columns Created Date and Modified Date it outputs the time as military time. I need it to ouput to normal time and displays whether it is a.m. or p.m. Can someone assist in what to add to the script to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the line:

```
"Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
```

to:

```
"Modified Date" = ($item["Modified"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
```

This will output the time as standard and not military time.